# android kotlin Flow emitted values are not collected

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-stateflow, kotlin-sharedflow

I have model class:

```
data class TweetResponse(
    val data: Data?,
    val matching_rules: List<ApiMatchingRule?>?,

    val lifeSpan: MutableStateFlow<Int>? = MutableStateFlow(30),
    var timer: CountDownTimer?
)
```

In my repository class I get list of these elements and emit them:

```
var tweetDataResponse = MutableSharedFlow<MutableList<TweetResponse>>()
var tweetList: MutableList<TweetResponse> = mutableListOf()

....some code

tweetResponse?.let { tweetList.add(it) }
tweetDataResponse.emit(tweetList)
```

My Viewmodel collects this list and start ticker for every item:

```
  private fun setCollectors() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            twitterRepository.tweetDataResponse.collect { response ->
                response.forEach {
                    it.timer = object : CountDownTimer(TWITTER_TIMER_COUNT) {
                        override fun onTick(remainingSeconds: Int) {
                            viewModelScope.launch {
                                it.lifeSpan?.emit(remainingSeconds)
                            }
                        }

                        override fun onFinish() {
                        }

                    }
                }
                tweetResponse.emit(response)
            }
        }
    }
```

also I emit this list to my fragment (tweetResponse.emit(response)) so it can give it to the corresponding adapter.

In my fragment I collect list and transfer it to adapter:

```
  private fun setCollectors() {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.CREATED) {
                viewModel.tweetResponse.collect {
                    adapter.addTweets(it)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And finally in adapter I set this list and bind it in onBIndViewholder:

```
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolderHome, position: Int) {
        val item = tweetList[position]

    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        item.lifeSpan?.collect { secondsLeft ->
            withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
                holder.binding.lifespan.text = secondsLeft.toString()
            }
        }
    }

          item.timer?.start()
}
```

As you can see, in onBind I set collector for every item and try to collect changes of lifespan flow variable. When I debug, my viewmodel does the ticking all the time and my collector in adapter is set properly. But values never get collected.
There is flaw somewhere, can I get some help in the friday night :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before looking at why it's not updating, the biggest glaring issue is your `onBindViewHolder` implementation. It is collecting an infinite flow (StateFlows are infinite) in a new abandoned CoroutineScope, so as you scroll up and down the list, you will have more and more obsolete coroutines running forever and leaking your views for the lifetime of your app. If you're going to start coroutines in `onBindViewHolder`, you need to run them in the associated `Activity`'s or `Fragment.viewLifecycleOwner`'s `lifecycleScope`, and furthermore you must store the launched `Job` in a property and cancel the old one before replacing it.

Also a general comment--you're using mutability way too much. It doesn't make sense to combine a `var` with a mutable collection or flow because then it's mutable in two different ways, which is likely to cause bugs.

It's very error prone to have a Flow of a mutable collection because it's ambiguous whether the emitted items are the same or not. They're *possibly* the same instance even if the content of the collection is changing, but there's no way to compare an item to the previous item if they're the same instance. If you put these in a StateFlow or use `distinctUntilChanged()`, it would be completely broken, but even without doing that, it is likely to cause bugs.

It's also quite convoluted that TweetResponse has a StateFlow for its life and also a Timer that's controlled from outside the class. It's a misuse of a data class to give it data properties that are not data. The Timer class doesn't have a proper `equals()` function, so your data class's `equals()` function will be broken.

There are so many possible avenues for failure here that I don't think it's worth attempting to analyze this code and figure out exactly why it's failing. I think it needs to be redesigned without all the mutability upon mutability everywhere.

Here's what I'd do. Give TweetResponse a simple `startTime` property. Then it doesn't have to have any moving parts or mutability. You can give it an extra property that's not in its constructor to return its time remaining. Then you only need to be checking and updating views in one place instead of running coroutines for every single tweet.

```
data class TweetResponse(
    val data: Data?,
    val matching_rules: List<ApiMatchingRule?>?,
    val startTime: Long = 0
) {
    val currentLifeRemaining: Long
        get() = (TWITTER_TIMER_COUNT - System.currentTimeMillis() + startTime).coerceAtLeast(0L)
}
```

Use `stateIn` where you declare the `tweetResponse` property for simpler code, and remove your `setCollectors()` function.

```
val tweetResponse = twitterRepository.tweetDataResponse.map { response ->
        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        response.map { it.copy(startTime = startTime) }
    }.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, emptyList())
```

Then in your adapter, you can run a single coroutine in an infinite loop with a one second delay that it uses to update all its currently visible views using `TweetResponse.currentLifeRemaining`.

Comment: I have just finished changing my implementation as you said and works like charm. Thanks mate, your answers are always pure gold

Comment: Would like to correct one part of your code if you don’t mind. When I implemented it, it wasn’t working and always showed 0 value on my views. I realized that in given code we miss division by 1000 when getting time (we take it in millis, not in seconds). So if you want you can change it. Not writting this to rub it or something, but when some other developer copy paste this code, not to make him surrender when he gets unexpected values